# How do I schedule a post in Drupal?

Tags: nodes

I was just wondering how one should go about scheduling a post in Drupal so that it posts at a point in time later then when you are posting? Is it as simple as changing the post time on the author information to a future point in time or is it more difficult then that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as simple as changing the post time at the point time that you would like to released that post

Comment: Thanks, wanted to be sure. Sometimes things that seem as easy as you can imagine never are.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post a page or article during a particular period of time. You can use the "[Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler)" module. This module allows nodes to be published and unpublished on specified dates. Very useful!